# Multiple Instantiate of 1 class affects memory?

Tags: java, memory, garbage-collection, memory-usage

I am currently struggling with memory handling. I have an if statement and each `case` instantiate a new object from a class. Does this affect the memory allocation in java?

```
switch()
{
case 1:
test t1 = new test();

case 2:
test t2 = new test();

case 3:
test t3 = new test();

case 4:
test t4 = new test();

case 5:
test t5 = new test();

case 6:
test t6 = new test();

}
```

Comment: Note that your `case`s have no `break`: unless you end each `case` with a `break` statement, execution will "fall through" to the next `case`.

More info: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/switch.html

Comment: Also note that, in Java, class names should start with a capital letter. And you must place a variable in the switch brackets, of course.

Answer (score 4):

No, it doesn't.

Each time your `case` is executed, exactly one object is allocated (except if you pass in an unhandled value, in which case nothing happens). The fact that there are a lot of `new` statements in your code doesn't change that; what counts is how often an allocation statement is *executed*, not when its byte code is loaded.

Comment: Thanks. got nosebleed on this "how often an allocation statement is executed, not when its byte code is loaded.". Can you site a piece of code. )

Comment: It's very important that you master the difference between *compile-time* and *run-time* events. Any code that changes the state of your program (not just allocation, but assignment, I/O and every other change) has that effect *only* when the control flow actually *reaches* it. If your code is within an `if` (or `case`) that is never executed, this never happens. If it is executed multiple times, it happens *several* times. this is why static analysis of program texts is so limited in what it can predict about program behaviour (it isn't even possible to predict wether a program terminates).